# Actions to speed up R calculations

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

I'm asking this as a general/beginner question about `R`, not specific to the package I was using.

I have a `dataframe` with 3 million rows and 15 columns.  I don't consider this a huge dataframe, but maybe I'm wrong.

I was running the following script and it's been running for 2+ hours - I imagine there must be something I can do to speed this up.

Code:

```
ddply(orders, .(ClientID), NumOrders=len(OrderID))
```

This is not an overly intensive script, or again, I don't think it is.

In a database, you could add an index to a table to increase join speed.  Is there a similar action in `R` I should be doing on import to make functions/packages run faster?

Comment: See the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/) package.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich data.table instead of dataframe?  Are they truly interchangeable?  Thanks

Comment: Came in to suggest `data.table` too. This op will be significantly faster and you can run the same bit of code once you convert your `data.frame` to `data.table`. `orders <- data.table(orders)`. That simple.

Comment: Just to explain, **plyr** is extremely popular due to its oh-so-sweet syntactic sugar, but it is slow for large data sets, particularly when the number of groups in your splitting variable is large. Spend some time learning data.table; the syntax isn't as nice (IMHO) but it will often be many orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: As a side note the plyr package is a terrific tool (easy syntax) but really not the best tool for larger sets of data and i would consider 3 million obs. a larger set but I'm in education and get excited about data sets of 100.

Comment: It's chewing on the `data.table` right now. I'll report back on the performance.  @joran if I am looking at aggregation and grouping, is there a better tool to use than `plyr`?  Thanks all

Comment: It sounds like `table(orders$ClientID)` might get you want you want too.

Comment: There are lots of questions on aggregation techniques. I put together a (relatively) exhaustive list in this question with timings for popular answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748253/idiomatic-r-code-for-partitioning-a-vector-by-an-index-and-performing-an-operati/10748470#10748470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the suggested `data.table` package, the following operation should do the job within a second:

```
orders[,list(NumOrders=length(OrderID)),by=ClientID]
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me that you might  want:

```
orders$NumOrders <- with( orders( ave(OrderID  , ClientID) , FUN=length) )
```

(I'm not aware that  len() function exists.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all your code is doing is this:

```
orders[order(orders$ClientID), ]
```

That would be faster.