# aggregate values from several fields into one

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregation

I have the following data frame in R:

```
objects   categories
   A       162
   B       162
   B       190
   C       123
   C       162
   C       185
   C       190
   C        82
   C       191
   D       185
```

As you see there are objects and the categories they belong to. I would like to sum up the categories of each object in comma separated list to get a data frame which would look like this:

```
 objects   categories
   A       162
   B       162, 190
   C       123, 162, 185, 190, 82, 191
   D       185
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with any of the aggregation tools of your choice, I'll show an example using `plyr` package and `paste()` function. This assumes your data is named `x`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(x, .(objects), summarize, categories = paste(categories, collapse = ","))
#-----
  objects             categories
1       A                    162
2       B                162,190
3       C 123,162,185,190,82,191
4       D                    185
```

Comment: The next logical question will be "which aggregation tool should I use?" I gave a pretty good effort answering that one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748253/idiomatic-r-code-for-partitioning-a-vector-by-an-index-and-performing-an-operati/10748470#10748470) should you be interested.

Answer (score 4):

```
aggregate(categories~objects,data=x,FUN=paste)
  objects                  categories
1       A                         162
2       B                    162, 190
3       C 123, 162, 185, 190, 82, 191
4       D                         185
```

Comment: Just beat me to it. I had posted `aggregate(list(categories=df$categories), by=list(objects=df$objects), c)`

Comment: @mrdwab I was just about to upvote it. I'd suggest undeleting it as using `c` may be preferable to `paste` if the OP wants to calculate with the numbers later.

Comment: true. I generally prefer `c` for flexibility further down the line. I had just felt the two responses were *so* much the same. Undeleted--we'll see what others think! :-)

Answer (score 2):

As the title of your question implies, use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(list(categories=df$categories), by=list(objects=df$objects), c)
#   objects                  categories
# 1       A                         162
# 2       B                    162, 190
# 3       C 123, 162, 185, 190, 82, 191
# 4       D                         185
```

Answer (score 1):

**aggregate** If `DF` is your data frame then try this:

```
aggregate(categories ~ objects, DF, function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```

**sqldf** With sqldf this works:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select objects, group_concat(distinct categories) as categories
  from DF group by objects")
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[,list(categories = list(categories)), by = objects]

##    objects             categories
## 1:       A                    162
## 2:       B                162,190
## 3:       C 123,162,185,190,82,191
## 4:       D                    185
```