# R finding duplicates in one column and collapsing in a second column

Tags: r, duplicates, aggregate

I have a data frame with two columns contacting character strings. in one column (named `probes`)  I have duplicated cases (that is, several cases with the same character string).  for each case in probes I want to find all the cases containing the same string, and then merge the values of all the corresponding cases in the second column (named `genes`) into a single case.
for example, if I have this structure:

```
    probes  genes
1   cg00050873  TSPY4
2   cg00061679  DAZ1
3   cg00061679  DAZ4
4   cg00061679  DAZ4
```

I want to change it to this structure:

```
    probes  genes
1   cg00050873  TSPY4
2   cg00061679  DAZ1 DAZ4 DAZ4
```

obviously there is no problem doing this for a single probe using which, and then paste and collapse

```
ind<-which(olap$probes=="cg00061679")
genename<-(olap[ind,2])
genecomb<-paste(genename[1:length(genename)], collapse=" ")
```

but I'm not sure how to extract the indices of the duplicates in probes column across the whole data frame. any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [R aggregate values from several fields into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635134/r-aggregate-values-from-several-fields-into-one)

Comment: Change the argument to `collapse = " "` in the answers to the above question and you have your answer(s).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tapply` in base R

```
data.frame(probes=unique(olap$probes), 
           genes=tapply(olap$genes, olap$probes, paste, collapse=" "))
```

or use plyr:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(olap, "probes", summarize, genes = paste(genes, collapse=" "))
```

**UPDATE**

It's probably safer in the first version to do this:

```
tmp <- tapply(olap$genes, olap$probes, paste, collapse=" ")
data.frame(probes=names(tmp), genes=tmp)
```

Just in case unique gives the probes in a different order to `tapply`. Personally I would always use `ddply`.

Answer (score 3):

Base R `aggregate()` should work fine for this:

```
aggregate(genes ~ probes, data = olap, as.vector)
#       probes            genes
# 1 cg00050873            TSPY4
# 2 cg00061679 DAZ1, DAZ4, DAZ4
```

I prefer `as.vector` in case I need to do any further work on the data (this stores the `genes` column as a `list`, but you can also try `aggregate(genes ~ probes, data=test, paste, collapse=" ")` if you prefer it to be a character string.