# in create a new variable with the max or min of another variable -- by group

Tags: r

R Community: I am trying to to create a new variable based on the value of existing variable, not on a row-wise basis but rather on a group-wise basis.  I'm trying to create `max.var` and `min.var` below based on `old.var` without collapsing or aggregating the rows, that is, preserving all the `id` rows:

```
id  old.var min.var max.var
1   1   1   3
1   2   1   3
1   3   1   3
2   5   5   11
2   7   5   11
2   9   5   11
2   11  5   11
3   3   3   4
3   4   3   4

structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), old.var = 
c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 3L, 4L), min.var = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L), max.var = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
4L, 4L)), .Names = c("id", "old.var", "min.var", "max.var"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I've tried using the `aggregate` and `by` functions, but they of course summarize the data.  I haven't had much luck trying an Excel-like MATCH/INDEX approach either.  Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Take a look at `?ave`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748253/idiomatic-r-code-for-partitioning-a-vector-by-an-index-and-performing-an-operati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ave` as docendo discimus pointed out in the question's comments:

```
df$min.var <- ave(df$old.var, df$id, FUN = min)
df$max.var <- ave(df$old.var, df$id, FUN = max)
```

Output:

```
  id old.var min.var max.var
1  1       1       1       3
2  1       2       1       3
3  1       3       1       3
4  2       5       5      11
5  2       7       5      11
6  2       9       5      11
7  2      11       5      11
8  3       3       3       4
9  3       4       3       4
```

Comment: I wanted to thank everyone.  I _knew_ I couldn't be the first person with this question: I just wasn't using the right SO search terms.  I selected mpalanco 's answer because I couldn't select the first answer from @docendo_discimus referenced here, and because it's the easiest for R newbies to understand, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dplyr`,

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(min.var = min(old.var), max.var = max(old.var))

#Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
#Groups: id [3]

#     id old.var min.var max.var
#  (int)   (int)   (int)   (int)
#1     1       1       1       3
#2     1       2       1       3
#3     1       3       1       3
#4     2       5       5      11
#5     2       7       5      11
#6     2       9       5      11
#7     2      11       5      11
#8     3       3       3       4
#9     3       4       3       4
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c('min.var', 'max.var') := list(min(old.var), max(old.var)) , by = id]
df1
#   id old.var min.var max.var
#1:  1       1       1       3
#2:  1       2       1       3
#3:  1       3       1       3
#4:  2       5       5      11
#5:  2       7       5      11
#6:  2       9       5      11
#7:  2      11       5      11
#8:  3       3       3       4
#9:  3       4       3       4
```